# router not working in Angular Property route does not exist on type

Tags: angular

I have following code :

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
..
..
export class ChangepasswordComponent implements OnInit {
..
  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder,
    route: ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient,private toastr: ToastrService) { 
    this.changePasswordForm = this.fb.group({
    .......
    }, {  validator: ConfirmedValidator('password', 'password_confirmation') })
    route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      this.changePasswordForm.controls['passwordToken'].setValue(params['token']);
    })

  }
  onSubmit(){
 this.route.navigate(['home']);
}
```

route.queryParams is working when retrieving value from url quesry string but onSubmit function `this.route.navigate(['home']);` does not work and error it shows is Property route does not exist on type.....

Thanks

Comment: add in constructor `public router: Router`
call in function `this.router.navigate(['home'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using improper dependency injection:

```
constructor(
    ...,
    route: ActivatedRoute,
    ...
) { }
```

Change it to:

```
constructor(
    ...,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ...
) { }
```

**UPDATE**: if you want to navigate router, you have to inject `Router` from `'@angular/router'` and use it:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
```

```
constructor(
    ...,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
    ...
) { }
```

```
this.router.navigate(['home']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i tried your code now it is showing navigate does not exist on type Activated route

Comment: @user3653474 I've updated my answer